# I can't use matplotlib from a script

Tags: python, matplotlib

Can somebody help me with this problem?

1. Python recognises matplotlib from the command line:

   ```
   import matplotlib
   matplotlib.__version__
   '3.4.3'
   ```
2. But not from a script

   This is my script (to keep it simple):

   ```
   import matplotlib.pylab as plt
   import numpy as np
   ```

These are the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Program Files/Python39/Scripts/matplotlib.py", line 1, in <module>

    import matplotlib.pylab as plt

  File "C:\Program Files/Python39/Scripts\matplotlib.py", line 1, in <module>

    import matplotlib.pylab as plt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pylab';
 
'matplotlib' is not a package
```

Comment: try this: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: Your script is called matplotlib.py. You need to rename it

Answer (score -1):

Try Reinstalling the package or downgrading it to a more stable version like 2.02

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question.  :-)
As it turns out renaming my file from matplotlib.py to plotting_with_mat.py worked like a charm.

Comment: Yes that also might be the problem as you cannot name a file the name of a package as it will not import correctly thus giving an error.